# Can I eat non halal slaughtered way chicken while on an educational trip?

Tags: food

Asalamalaikum. I live in US but I'll be going on an educational trip to Argentina and Chile for 2 weeks and over there I'll be with my College peers and professors to even go to restaurants with them. I may not get halal food over there and also hardly any vegetarian. So, I'm wondering is it allowed for me on the tour to eat non-halal way slaughtered chicken? I've seen Muslims in US eating non-halal way slaughtered chicken by simply saying Bismillah (I know this is not allowed) But is it allowed on a trip? Thank you

Comment: Brother you’ve said yourself that it’s not allowed so why would there be an exception for a trip?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our 2 minutes [tour] and checking our [help]. Exceptions require dire need, i.e. one would die if not doing it. Further it is mainly halal to eat from the food of the people of the book.

Answer (score -2):

No you can’t Allah clearly said in quran

“And do not eat that upon which the name of Allah has not been mentioned,for indeed it is a grave disobedience”
(6:121)

Comment: This really needs some elaboration, see [answer].